# Hadoop YARN - how to limit requestedMemory?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Trying to run the PI example from the `hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar`, I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException): Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory > max configured, requestedMemory=1536, maxMemory=512
```

Not sure where the 1536 came from, but the 512 is the max heap size I set to the child task in `mapred-site.xml`:

```xml
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
  <value>512</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx410m</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
  <value>512</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx410m</value>
</property>
```

What is the correct way to determine the size of map/reduce tasks?

Answer (score 6):

512 is the default value of `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`  in `yarn-site.xml`, and 1536 is the default value of  `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb` parameter in `mapred-site.xml`.

Make sure that `allocation-mb` > `app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb`, and it  will be ok.